# blank spaces, number must start with +

Tags: regex

I need to get a regex where a phone number must begin with a +. There can be a comma seperated list eg
List:

```
tel1: +E1234498912345678@fake.com, tel2: +498912345678, tel1: +E123449D1238912345678@fake.com
```

is a valid list. E is a valid special case

My regex is this:

```
^(tel1:)|(tel2:)( )(\+.)$
```

but it accepts numbers without a + as being valid which is not what I want. The number MUST be preceded by a + otherwise it's invalid. Any hints?

Comment: You need to tag what language you're using the regex in.

Comment: Are `tel1` and `tel2` part of the regex?

Comment: Yeah, will be one or the other

Comment: No, not a moment. Choice for now tel1/tel2. I know how to extend it further if tel3 was also valid but not needed for now

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
(tel[12]:\s*\+[eE]?\w+(@\w+(\.\w+)+)?(,\s*)?)+
```

This should match telephone numbers separated by a comma, in a single line.

It also oversees the use of a special character **E** or **e**.

Also, domains may not only end in **.com**. **.net** or **.com.uk** should also be valid.